# SSL Virtualhosts not working upon reboot, unless Apache2 Manually restarted

Tags: 12.04, apache2, reboot, ssl, virtualhost

I have a few SSL Virtualhosts and they work fine until I restart the box. Then all of the SSL virtualhosts point to the directory listed in default-ssl. If I restart Apache2 service manually everything works as intended. any ideas?

Comment: Are the IP addresses of those virtualhosts already assigned to an interface when Apache starts?

Comment: the interface is set manually

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like that the IP addresses of the virtual hosts are not yet assigned when Apache starts. I suggest you to have a look at `/var/log/apache2/error.log` for any errors and adjust the boot order of Apache and the assignment of addresses.

Comment: I dont see any errors  listed in the log :(
only [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3 with Suhosin-Patch mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/1.0.1 configured -- resuming normal operations

Comment: What about `/var/log/boot.log` or even `/var/log/syslog`?

Comment: nothing in boot.log, and nothing noticable in syslog from apache

Comment: Please check the `sudo netstat -tlpn` output after rebooting. Where do you set additional IP addresses? `/etc/network/interfaces`?

Comment: The system has just one IP set from the control panel on the desktop.
                   
tcp    0   0 0.0.0.0:80     0.0.0.0:*     LISTEN      1231/apache2
tcp    0   0 0.0.0.0:443    0.0.0.0:*     LISTEN      1231/apache2